# Python C Extension in package - not working?

Tags: python, packaging, python-c-extension

I'm working on packaging my python C extension and I'm running into trouble here:

```
.
|-- c_ext/
|   |-- __init__.py
|-- c_src/
setup.py
```

With this setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup( name = "Utilities",
       version = '1.0',
       description = ('Various utils'),
       packages = ["utils"],
       ext_modules = [Extension("utils.c_ext", ['c_src/c_extmodule.c'])]
       )
```

I can build without problems but after installing I can't import my module, I just get an ImportError.

I'm sure it's something trivial, so what am I missing?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a function in your module with the following signature:

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC initc_ext(void);
```

When you import a C extension it calls the function init where  is the exact name of the extension.  (Note that the convention is for C extensions to be named something like _foo and you get a function like init_foo)

The exact error would also help diagnose this better.